# Transform flat array of objects intro tree

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, tree

I have a flat array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "a",
    parent-id: ""
  },
  {
    id: "b",
    parent-id: "a"
  },
  {
    id: "c",
    parent-id: "b"
  },
  {
    id: "d",
    parent-id: ""
  },
  ...
]
```

I would like to parse this flat array into a tree-structure, where objects with parent-ids are inserted as child elements of their parent like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "a",
    parent-id: "",
    children: [
      {
        id: "b",
        parent-id: "a",
        children: [
          {
            id: "c",
            parent-id: "b"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d",
    parent-id: ""
  },
  ...
]
```

It doesn't matter if the transformation happens on the client or the server, so my options are PHP or JS. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: the language does not matter here because the code will be nearly the same

Comment: Well, this looks straight forward, you have to iterate through the array and place the objects one by one. I can't really see what the question is here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can try:

```
$foo = // your flat array of associative arrays


// add the top level nodes to an array

$result = array();
foreach ($foo as $node) {
    if ($node['parent-id'] === '') {
        $node['children'] = array();
        array_push($result, $node);
    }
}

// recursively iterate this array adding the children

addChildrenToArray($result, $foo);

function addChildrenToArray(&$array, $children) {
    $parent_i = 0;
    $child_i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $parent_node) {
        foreach ($children as $child_node) {
            if ($child_node['parent-id'] == $parent_node['id']) {
                $child_node['children'] = array();
                array_push($array[$parent_i]['children'], $child_node);
                addChildrenToArray($array[$parent_i]['children'], $children);
                $child_i++;
            }
        }
        $parent_i++;
    }
}
```